# Transfer Highscores and Data

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I'm writing a game write now which involves saving highscores and basic data such as "soundeffects on" and "music on" onto a plist file.
However, when in the future, I need to update my game and upload a new version of the app onto users' iphones/ipods, how will the highscores be retained? Is there a way to save specific plist files while overwriting others? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Is there any way to overwrite PART of a plist or merge an existing plist with a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're putting these plists in the documents directory, there's nothing further you need to do.  These files are all retained when your app is upgraded.  You get the documents directory like this:

```
+ (NSString*) documentsPath
{
    NSArray* sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
    return [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: What if, for instance, I have two plists.. One of them, I can retain, but the second one, I want to add more elements to it. The second plist, called the "storeplist" right now has 10 elements. Each element, in turn, has sub elements which have properties which must be retained. In future updates, if I want to add to the list without affecting the properties that existed before, how would I do so? Thanks again!

Comment: Is there any possible way to overwrite PART of a plist or merge an existing one with a new one? Thank you!